# How to Limit data for Max[Fiscal_Year] and Max[Fiscal_Month]

Tags: business-intelligence, spotfire

I have 2 columns named Fiscal_Year and Fiscal_Month . Fiscal year is integer type and fiscal month is string type . Now I want that visualization should show data for max[fiscal_month] in accordance to max[fiscal_year].For eg if data contains month till sept for year 2021 then data should show only sept month data for year 2021.

Any idea how do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First Concat the columns of month and year,Then convert it into date format eg.Date(Concatenate([Month],"/",[Year])),make sure the date format is MM-yyyy which will get you a column with format like 09-2021. Now Create any visualization and go to show/hide section and show only data with max month.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).